# Search and Select Item Modal for ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, bootstrap-modal

I'm new to ASP.NET and to web development itself but have been able to understand quite well how controllers and views (MVC) work at the basics. I managed to create a Create view with a Master-Details page and save to the database by manually adding items to the corresponding list of Products (Id and quantity).
However that very page must allow to add such products by searching them in a reusable (partial view?) Product Search modal.

Scenario:
I've a View bound to Recipe model (which includes an ICollection). When I click on Search Product in the ingredient line, a modal needs to be shown with several search criteria (at the moment I need at least a searchable input box or dropdown like Select2 for looking up the Product). After selecting the product in the modal, such should be added to the corresponding ingredient line.

If possible, it would be better to make this without using JavaScript. I guess it should be possible by passing the Recipe with its ingredients to the modal, then add the Product to the Recipe object in the modal, and reloading that in the caller form (if there were 3 lines, then after selecting the new product there would be 4 ingredients).

Note: I need something like this, but with best practices, and also updated :)
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1183240/Modal-Search-and-Select-Item-Dialog-for-ASP-NET

Depending on the guides I've been following and other things I tried, these have been my issues:

** I've been struggling to find an example/article/video/post/answer/course that is not simple Add/Create operations where all the data needed for creating the new object is loaded in the same modal/form. Also, ChatGPT has not been able to reach this level of complexity (maybe I did not describe my problem right to it).

** When defining the modal in a partial view, it seems not being able to be found by the caller button (nothing happens when clicked). However, if I define it in the same .cshtml file, it is shown with no issue (however since that view is bound to Recipe I can't use a list of Products to populate the dropdown, for example. I have read that you can have a custom ViewModel with both Recipe and Products inside but haven't been able to implement it right I think)

** I managed to show the modal with a dropdown loaded with the Products using Select2 and passing the list of Products in ViewBag.Products, but for some reason it is shown as a classic webforms dropdown (maybe bootstrap and script for searching not applied?)

**TLDR:**

- Main issue: send selected product back to recipe-creation page and show it added to the list of ingredients
- Other issues:

- show searchable control for Products
- other aspects you find necessary

Providing me with links that help me understand underlying concepts would also be very helpful

::CODE::
Note1 -> Please note that I'm actually using Spanish words and have translated from it. e.g.: Will try and make sure I use "Recipe" instead of "Receta"

Note 2 -> CreateRecipe.cs only has code for adding and removing an ingredient line and showing the Add and Remove buttons

**Recipe.cs**

```js
namespace WebApp.Models
{
    public class Recipe
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Result { get; set; } // Kg.
        public int Time{ get; set; }      // Minutes
        public virtual List<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set;}
    }
}
```

**Ingredient.cs**

```js
namespace WebApp.Models
{
    public class Ingrediente
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public double Quantity { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Article")]
        [Column("idModels")]
        public long ArticleId { get; set; }
        public virtual Article Article { get; set; }
        
        public int RecipeId { get; set; }
        public virtual Recipe Recipe { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Article.cs**

```js
namespace WebApp.Models
{
    [Table("models")]
    public class Article
    {
        [Key]
        public int idModels { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Artícle")]
        public string mod_name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Recipe Controller**

```js
namespace WebApp.Controllers
{
    public class RecipeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly WebAppContext _context;

        public RecipeController(WebAppContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

       

        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // *** List of recipes in the database, with ability to edit, view details and delete them ***
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // GET: Recipes

        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return _context.Recipe != null ?
                        View(await _context.Recipe.ToListAsync()) :
                        Problem("Entity set 'WebApp.Recipe'  is null.");
        }



        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // *** Go to the recipe-adding View ***
        // *** If coming from Index view, create Recipe object in memory ***
        // *** If it's bringing a recipe with its ingredients up to this point, it will be loaded using the binding ***
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // GET: Recipe/Create

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Create()
        {            
            Receta sampleRecipe = new Recipe
            {                
                Ingredients = new List<Ingredient>
                {
                    new Ingredient
                    {                        
                    }                    
                }
            };

            if (ViewData["NewArticle"] != null)
            {
                var newArticle = ViewData["NewArticle"] as Article;
                sampleRecipe.Ingredients.Add(new Ingredient() { ArticleId = newArticle.idModels, Quantity = 1000 });
            }

            List<Article> listArticles = _context.Article.ToList();
            ViewBag.Articles = listArticles;

            return View(sampleRecipe);
        }





        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // *** Load articles in the modal to select one ***
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // GET
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult ShowModalController(Recipe savedRecipe)
        {
            return PartialView("_SearchArticle", savedRecipe);
        }



        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // *** Add article to in-memory-recipe's ingredient in memory ***
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        // POST
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult ConfirmArticle(Recipe savedRecipe)
        {
            ????

            return View("Create", savedRecipe);
        }



        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // *** Save recipe with its ingredients ***
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------     
        // POST: Recipe/Create

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Name,Result,Time, Ingredients")] Recipe recipe)
        {
                _context.Add(receta);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
           
        }
    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```html
@model WebApp.Models.Recipe

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<div class="col-11 mx-auto pt-0">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header bg-success text-uppercase text-white">
            <h4>Add recipe</h4>
        </div>
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Result" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Result" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Result" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Time" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Time" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Time" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>                    

                    @* List of ingredients for the recipe*@

                    <div id="ListIngredients" class="col-md-12">
                        <table id="TableIngredients" class="table table-striped table-sm">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col">Article</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
                                    <th scope="col"></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
               
                                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Ingredients.Count; i++)
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Ingredients[i].ArticleId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })                                               
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Ingredients[i].Cantidad, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })                                                
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @* Add a button as a placeholder in order to make room to Add and Remove buttons  *@
                                            @* @i is added to uniquely name row buttons *@
                                            <button id="btndummy-@i" type="button" class="btn btn-sm invisible">Dummy</button>

                                            <button id="AddIngredientButton-@i"
                                                    onclick="NewLineIngredient(this)" type="button"
                                                    style="left:45%;position:absolute;"
                                                    class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary visible">
                                                Add
                                            </button>

                                            <button id="RemoveIngredientButton-@i"
                                                    onclick="RemoveLineIngredient(this)" type="button"
                                                    style="left:45%;position:absolute;"
                                                    class="btn btn-sm btn-danger invisible">
                                                Remove
                                            </button>
                                           
                                                                                         
                                            <button id='chooseArticle' class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal"
                                                data-bs-target="#modalChooseArticle" data-url="@Url.Action("ShowModalController")">Choose article</button>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                }                                
                            </tbody>                            
                        </table>                        
                    </div>

                    <input type="hidden" id="HiddenLastIndex" value="0" />

                    <div class="col-12 btn-group">
                        <div class="form-group col-6 text-right p-2">
                            <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-secondary">&nbsp;Cancel&nbsp;</a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group col-6 text-left p-2">
                            <input type="submit" value="Confirm" class="btn btn-primary" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

<div id="modalChooseArticle" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">

            @{
                Html.RenderPartial("_SearchArticle", ViewBag.Articles as IEnumerable<Article>); // Partial view and its binding model
            }
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->    

@section Scripts {
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }

    <script src="/js/CreateReceta.js">        
    </script>
}
```

**_SearchArticle.cshtml**

```html
<div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            
</div>

<div class="modal-body">
    <form asp-action="ConfirmArticle" method="post">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Article name</label>
            <select class="dropdownListClass" name="dropdownListName">
                @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Articulos)
                {
                    <option value="@item.idModels">@item.mod_name</option>
                        }
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
        </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: Hi,@Jonathan Cumini,please show your codes related so that we could understand your problem better

Comment: Thank you for taking a look @RuikaiFeng. I've just added the code. Please let me know anything you may need for further clarifying

Answer (score 0):

> Main issue: send selected product back to recipe-creation page and
> show it added to the list of ingredients

You could try move this part of codes into a partial view which shares the same viewmodel with  View `Create`

```
@* List of ingredients for the recipe*@

                    <div id="ListIngredients" class="col-md-12">
                        <table id="TableIngredients" class="table table-striped table-sm">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col">Article</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
                                    <th scope="col"></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
               
                                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Ingredients.Count; i++)
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Ingredients[i].ArticleId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })                                               
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Ingredients[i].Cantidad, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })                                                
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @* Add a button as a placeholder in order to make room to Add and Remove buttons  *@
                                            @* @i is added to uniquely name row buttons *@
                                            <button id="btndummy-@i" type="button" class="btn btn-sm invisible">Dummy</button>

                                            <button id="AddIngredientButton-@i"
                                                    onclick="NewLineIngredient(this)" type="button"
                                                    style="left:45%;position:absolute;"
                                                    class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary visible">
                                                Add
                                            </button>

                                            <button id="RemoveIngredientButton-@i"
                                                    onclick="RemoveLineIngredient(this)" type="button"
                                                    style="left:45%;position:absolute;"
                                                    class="btn btn-sm btn-danger invisible">
                                                Remove
                                            </button>
                                           
                                                                                         
                                            <button id='chooseArticle' class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal"
                                                data-bs-target="#modalChooseArticle" data-url="@Url.Action("ShowModalController")">Choose article</button>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
```

Create  a blank div in your form ,when you click the save button in modal,make an ajax call pass the required arguments (`ArticleId` you selected?) to controller,then refresh this part

```
$("#save").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "Ingredient",
            .......
            success:function(result){
                $("#blankdiv").html(result)
            }
        })
    })
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with JS or ajax and though I can read it, this explanation is not clear enough for me. Is there a way I can do this with asp.net core only/mostly? I think of two options: 1) passing the Recipe model to the modal and adding it the ingredient in the modal. Then passing the updated Recipe back to the invoking view so it can show updated values; 2) passing an Article model from the modal to the invoking view through ViewData  (I need to show article name in the list of ingredients so ArticleId is not enough I guess). Thank you!